# Can QT 5.12.x and above version support OpenGL sparse texture feature - ARB_sparse_texture - call glTexPageCommitmentARB()

Tags: qt, opengl, textures, sparse-matrix

Can QT 5.12.x and above version support OpenGL sparse texture feature - ARB_sparse_texture - call glTexPageCommitmentARB()?

When I complile the code and get the link error:

"error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glTexPageCommitmentARB referenced in function xxxx"

Which library in QT5.12.x or above version has this glTexPageCommitmentARB such as support sparse texture functions? Thanks

My configuration:

```
QT5.12.10(release version download from QT.io, not compile and build by myself)
Visual Studio 2015
add "GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES" in "C/C++/Preprocessor" in project properties so that enable the definition of "glTexPageCommitmentARB" in qopenglext.h
```

#ifdef GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
GLAPI void APIENTRY glTexPageCommitmentARB (GLenum target, GLint level, GLint xoffset, GLint yoffset, GLint zoffset, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLsizei depth, GLboolean commit);
#endif

```
These libraries are set in project "link/input/additional dependencies“
Qt5OpenGLExtensionsd.lib
Qt53DRenderd.lib
Qt5OpenGLd.lib
Qt5Svgd.lib
Qt5Widgetsd.lib
Qt5Guid.lib
Qt5Networkd.lib
Qt5Xmld.lib
Qt5Cored.lib
OpenGL32.lib
glu32.lib
```